# HTML/PHP sending mail shouldnt reload window

Tags: php, html, email, web

I want to send an E-Mail from my Website:

```
<form action="../php/mail.php" method="POST">
...
```

The code works, but every time I click the "Submit"-Button, the browser navigates to the ../php/mail.php.

How can I stop that?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: the easiest way should work with jQuery and `$.POST()`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/  have you tried this?

Comment: @rob yup that's right

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` redirection:

```
<script>    
window.location.replace("<?php echo $url; ?>");
</script>
```

put this script at the end of `php/mail.php` file, value `$url` with the url of the current address.